# compare password using sequelize fn and postgres built in crypt

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

i know compare password using bcrypt module is work too, but out of curiousity, i want to know if there is a away to using sequelize fn and postgres crypt?

i already try this :

```
const user = await Users.findOne({ 
  where: { 
    username: myUsername,
    password: sequelize.fn('crypt',myPassword,'password')
  } 
});
```

but not work because in the queries look like

```
SELECT "id", "username", "password", FROM "users" AS "Users" 
WHERE "Users"."username" = 'yosiazwan' AND "Users"."password" = crypt('testing', 'password');
```

'password' is in single quotes when it should not. if i try that queries in pgadmin, it doesn't work too. but if i remove the 'password' single quotes, like this

```
SELECT "id", "username", "password", FROM "users" AS "Users" 
WHERE "Users"."username" = 'yosiazwan' AND "Users"."password" = crypt('testing', password);
```

and that will works. is there any way to remove that single quotes in sequelize fn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#static-method-fn](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#static-method-fn)

> `public static fn(fn: string, args: any): fn since v2.0.0-dev3`
>
> Creates an object representing a database function. This can be used
> in search queries, both in where and order parts, and as default
> values in column definitions. **If you want to refer to columns in your
> function, you should use `sequelize.col`, so that the columns are
> properly interpreted as columns and not a strings.**

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#static-method-col](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#static-method-col)

> `public static col(col: string): col since v2.0.0-dev3`
>
> Creates an object which represents a column in the DB, this allows
> referencing another column in your query. This is often useful in
> conjunction with `sequelize.fn`, since raw string arguments to fn will
> be escaped.

Your code should look like

```
const user = await Users.findOne({ 
  where: { 
    username: myUsername,
    password: sequelize.fn('crypt',myPassword, sequelize.col('password'))
  } 
});
```